# Square AC adapter wire connector

Tags: connector

I've never seen this type before and don't know what type of connector I need to add to the wires to connect to it. I've looked on Google and haven't seen it. What type of connector is this (the green thing in the photo)? How do I add the appropriate connectors to the wire so they can plug in?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't guarantee that this is the correct one because i can't measure it but this is similar to what your looking for.

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-shore-technology-inc/OSTTJ0231530/ED2875-ND/1588450
[image]

Comment: I found a [part](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/phoenix-contact/5444262/277-11313-ND/4368763) that looks exactly like it but I don't know the corresponding part

Comment: @user193661 the link i posted matches your part

Comment: The width of the header openings is 3mm, does that mean the pitch of the plug should be 3mm? The linked plug is 3.81mm. I don't see any 3mm plugs on digikey either.

Comment: @user193661 No, the pitch is the center of one pin to the center of the pin next to it. The link to the plug you posted has a pitch of 3.81mm and the plug i posted has a pitch of 3.81mm.